# Why is "cat" alike to the corresponding word in other languages whereas "dog" is not?

Tags: etymology

I realized that *cat* sounds very alike to other indoeuropean languages (*katze*, *katt*, *kot*, *gato*) while *dog* is wildly different. I can't find any language where *dog* is spelled nor pronounced *doggishly* (for lack of a better word).

As far my goolearching went, the domesticated species have appeared more or less at the same time and so long ago that the linguistic discrepancy can't be explained by it. Both are equally common and well seen.

Any ideas on the origing of the difference?

Comment: It is from Old English **docga**, attested in an oblique case glossing Latin *canum*:  [canum docgena]. Cognate with German  *dogge*, *docke*, Swedish *dogg*, and Danish *dogge*.

Comment: I maybe wrong, but the significance given to *cats* were a little more than what the *dog* received, in history. For example, if you look at Egyptian history, cats have played a big role in their folklore and stories. Maybe there are more ancient literary remains of 'cats' than that of dogs. I maybe wrong, but it's just an observation. But if you compare the frequency of 'cat' and 'dog' being used in literature, from 1800, you'll be surprised at the result. But then again, this is just an opinion.

Comment: Take a look at this [Related Question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16377/where-does-the-word-dog-come-from)

Comment: Hehe *doggishly*... I've got to start using that word :D

Comment: Etymology questions are not really a good fit here. Seems like this would be better on ELU.

Comment: @TRomano Hmm... I believe in Swedish it's *hund*, not *dogg*. Am I missing your point, please?

Comment: @VarunKN I'm not sure how to pull out such statistiscs. Would you be a sport and help me. I'll gladly be surprised, hehe.

Comment: @Konrad Viltersten  Hmm...Try looking it up in dictionary of Swedish that includes archaic forms.   Holthausen in his *Altenglisches Etymologisches Woerterbuch* says the origin is unknown, conjecturing that it may be related to a ProtoGermanic word that meant "having ability, strength". But your initial premise is incorrect.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on English Language and Usage (ELU).

Comment: @TRomano I looked it up and apparently [there's *dogg* in Swedish](http://www.svenskaakademien.se/svenska-spraket/svenska-akademiens-ordlista-saol/saol-13-pa-natet/sok-i-ordlistan) but it means *a race of a dog*. However I can imagine that you're talking about even more archaic form not covered by it, so I probably stand corrected.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seriously has no answer. Different languages can choose to use a different word for a concept than its cognates at a whim; there is no why, but there is a what and how.

Comment: @Nihilist_Frost I disagree with your motivation in this particular case. In general, you're right - different languages may very well have totally different words for a concept. However, here, cats and dogs are both very common and widely incorporated into our culture, among other similarities, so the discrepancy is interesting. Also, there **is** an answer, if you take a peek below. (Please c.f. [this](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/29028/why-are-germans-referred-to-so-differently-in-different-languages).)

Comment: It is not a "discrepancy" that English has both "hound" and "dog"  whereas other Germanic languages do not nowadays have both.  A *hound* in English is a class of hunting dog (sight-hounds, scent-hounds).

Comment: @TRomano I'm afraid that I wasn't clear. The discrepancy I referred to was that one animal has a similar naming across languages whereas the other doesn't, despite similar properties.

Comment: What is "naming"?

Comment: @TRomano In this context, it's the process of assigning names to entities, concepts etc.

Comment: What you're asking is, Why in English do we have two words,**hound** and **dog**, the latter being the term for the generic beast, the former for a "dog bred to hunting", when in other Germanic languages, **dog** is a now archaic form that seems to have been associated with a particular large breed, and **hund--**  is the name for the generic beast?  What this question has to do with "cat" escapes me. We do not have hunting cats, or herding cats, or guard cats, or seeing-eye cats; the history of cat-breeding is hardly comparable to the history of dog breeding.

Comment: @TRomano I believe the base for why my question might seem unclear to you is that you're making the incorrect assumption as to its aim. I'm not entirely sure how to clarify it further at the moment, other than to repeat it (which, of course, won't give you new insight and only sound like I'm taunting - something I really don't). At any rate, I can point out that the summary of my question in your comment isn't accurate as to what's intended by me, the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a great mystery.

The Old English word was *Hund*, from which we get modern "Hound". There was a word, only found in one Old English source *docga*. The meaning of this word is rather unclear, it seems to have been a large powerful type of dog. This rare word, in a very short time, became the common word for dogs in Middle English, from the middle of the 1200s onwards. The word was subsequently picked up other languages (eg Danish "Dogge" is from the English). By 1700, the word dog was the only general term.

It is likely that the word "dog" had existed in English slang or dialect for sometime before 1200, but had not been used in the formal writing. It is very unusual for a word to appear to come out of nowhere. The word "dog" is rather special in this way.

Cat, on the other hand has a etymology from an African word, borrowed into Latin as Cattus (replacing earlier feles). Germanic languages borrowed the word from Latin, and so Latin and Germanic languages all have a similar word. (Romanian has pisica, related to pussy)

Comment: Cool. Polish has *pies*, which resembles the Romani word. Russian, however, has *sobaka*. We have the proverb saying *a loved child goes by many names*, so I guess dogs are beloved animals.

Comment: I think this is a very good observation. We do have lots of pet names for our pets! Sometimes, one of these pet names (which may not have been recorded in literature) replaces the formal word. "Puss" has no obvious source, and is probably an imitation of the sound you make to attract a cat's attention.

Comment: The word *docga* is from an Old English gloss.  In Middle English, the word **dog** was very well attested from 1230 on. http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?size=First+100&type=orths&q1=dog&rgxp=constrained

Comment: @TRomano You are right and I have corrected my answer.